# How to expose a docker container to access host database?

Tags: django, database, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to figure out **how to configure my `docker-compose.yml` to allow a web-server (django) to communicate with a PostgreSQL database running on the host machine.**

The app is perfectly working outside of a container.

And now I want to create a container for better management and deployment capabilities.

I've tried this,
**docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - .:/appdir
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=test
      - DB_USER=test
      - DB_PASSWORD=test
      - DB_HOST=localhost
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
```

**Dockerfile** :

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings \
    DEBUG=True \
    SECRET_KEY=akey

WORKDIR /appdir

COPY . /appdir

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But when I do so, I get the following error :

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` is relative - inside the docker container - localhost (aka 127.0.0.1) refers to the container itself. if you want to connect to your host- give the container your host real ip as the `DB_HOST`.

there are many ways to find your host ip, for instance: 
run in your terminal `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: You could also use the gateway IP of the respective Docker network to refer to the "real" localhost.